# How to leverage CumulusCI keywords when integrating with BrowserStack?

Tags: selenium, salesforce, robotframework, browserstack

Unable to understand how to leverage "Open Test Browser" which is a Cumulusci keyword when launching Salesforce url on Browserstack?

Project background:
I am building an automation framework (for functional/regression tests) for a Salesforce product using Robot Framework, SeleniumLibrary and CumulusCI and need to scale up automation capabilities to execute same tests on multiple browsers/OS for which I am integrating it with BrowserStack.

Implementation level details:
RFW and Cci is integrated correctly and works perfect on any scratch org locally in Chrome or FF. Here I can directly leverage the full power of Cci keywords such as "Open Test Browser" which knows the org details such as instance_url, username and password and has a access token. So logging into the Org is cakewalk. Here launching the SF url does not ask me for a email verification code.

```
*** Settings ***

Resource  cumulusci/robotframework/Salesforce.robot
Library  cumulusci.robotframework.CumulusCI  ${ORG}
library  SeleniumLibrary  timeout=20
library  OperatingSystem
library  Collections
library  XML
library  String
library  BuiltIn

*** Variables ***
${BSUser}  myBSkey
${BSAccessKey}  s******************b
${BSUrl}  http://${BSUser}:${BSAccessKey}@hub.browserstack.com/wd/hub

###Login Page Locators
${signOn_username}  //input[@id='username']
${signOn_password}  //input[@name='pw']
${loginButton}  //input[@name='Login']

###Home Page Locators
${SetupRecentlyViewed}  //div[@class='module-header']/div/header/h2/span

*** Test Cases ***
Connect RFW with BS
    ${instance_url}  ${username}  ${password}  Log my Org Info  #User keyword
    Setup BS Browser  ${instance_url}  ${username}  ${password}  #User keyword

*** Keywords ***
Log my Org Info
    &{OrgInfoDict}=  Get Org Info  #Cci keyword
    :FOR    ${key}    IN    @{OrgInfoDict.keys()}
    \   ${instance_url}=  Get From Dictionary    ${OrgInfoDict}    instance_url
    \   ${username}=  Get From Dictionary    ${OrgInfoDict}    username
    \   ${password}=  Get From Dictionary    ${OrgInfoDict}    password
    [Return]  ${instance_url}  ${username}  ${password}

Setup BS Browser
    [Arguments]  ${instance_url}  ${username}  ${password}
    Open Browser  url=${instance_url}  remote_url=${BSUrl}  desired_capabilities=browser:Safari,browser_version:12.0,os:OS X,os_version:Mojave,browserstack.video:True
    Maximize Browser Window
    Login to Salesforce  ${username}  ${password}

Login to Salesforce  [Arguments]  ${Username}  ${Password}
    Input Text  ${signOn_username}  ${Username}
    Input Text  ${signOn_password}  ${Password}
    Click Element  ${loginButton}
    ${Pass}=  RUN KEYWORD AND RETURN STATUS  Wait Until Page Contains Element  ${SetupRecentlyViewed}
    run keyword if  '${Pass}'=='True'  Log  "SF Home page loaded successfully"
    ...  ELSE  Fail  "SF Home page did not load successfully"
```

Actual Issue:
After referring to RFW and BrowserStack integrations on the internet (some links below), I was able to connect to BS but using Selenium keyword "Open Browser". I also tried to get all of my Org info and pass it on to BS to log into the SF url. When I do this, because I am using Selenium and not in the context of Cci, my SF org now throws email verification at me. Hence I feel I am falling short of understanding how to make use of the Cci context when running tests on BrowserStack.
Ref: https://www.swtestacademy.com/browserstack-robotframework-integration/ and https://github.com/knightjacky/Robot-BrowserStack

Workarounds tried:
I tried creating a webdriver and then using "Open Test Browser" that one also doesnt work, because as expected, it does not have a context of Cci Org.

```
*** Keywords ***
Create a BS WebDriver
   #Some code that creates a dict...
   #${executor}=  Evaluate  str('${BSUrl}')
   #Create Webdriver  Remote  desired_capabilities=${desired_capabilities}  command_executor=${executor}
   #Open Test Browser  #Cci keyword
```

Expected thoughts:
Please share some ideas as to how I can tweak my current implementation to make use of Cci keywords and not rely on Selenium when integrating with BrowserStack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, the salesforce keyword `Open test browser` doesn't support using the `create webdriver` keyword. However, it's easy to duplicate what `Open test browser` does. The key is to use a URL which contains the properly encoded credentials.

The keyword `Login URL` from the CumulusCI library will return you an appropriate url. You can then use this url with any browser no matter how the browser was opened.

### Example:

The following example will use a default browser on browserstack and then logs in to my default org. You can also pass an org into the `Login URL` keyword if you wish.

```
*** Settings ***
Resource        cumulusci/robotframework/Salesforce.robot
Suite Setup     Setup BS Browser
Suite Teardown  Delete records and close browser

*** Variables ***
${BSUser}       <your username here>
${BSAccessKey}  <your access key here>
${BSUrl}        http://${BSUser}:${BSAccessKey}@hub.browserstack.com:80/wd/hub

*** Keywords ***
Setup BS Browser
    Create Webdriver  Remote   command_executor=${BSUrl}
    ${login_url}  Login URL
    go to  ${login_url}
    Wait until loading is complete

*** Test Cases ***
Example using 'create webdriver'
    capture page screenshot
```

---

Note: The salesforce keyword `Open Test Browser` does a bit more than just open the browser: it also installs two location strategies. If you're not calling `Open Test Browser` and you want to use those location strategies, you will need to register them yourself:

```
Add Location Strategy  text   Locate Element By Text
Add Location Strategy  title  Locate Element By Title
```

Comment: Thanks a ton @Bryan Oakley, your solution works as expected and serves my purpose.